# Ground topology in step-down converter diagrams

Tags: pcb-design, dc-dc-converter, ground

ST sometimes draws grounds in particular ways on its circuit diagrams.  For example  [L5973AD datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/l5973ad.pdf), fig. 1. (L); [Application Note 2823](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an2823-current-source-for-led-driving-based-on-the-l5973ad-stmicroelectronics.pdf), fig. 5. (R).

[image]

**What does it mean we should do on the PCB layout?**  Its guidance on PCB layout only speaks of the current loop between Cin-pin8-pin1-D

[image]
[ST Application Note 1723](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/an1723-designing-with-l5973ad-high-efficiency-dcdc-converter-stmicroelectronics.pdf).

To me that looks like it should be drawn like this on the diagram:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0ibZC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It's a bit like a 4-wire measurement. It's the same idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What does it mean we should do on the PCB layout?*

It means that you should use star-pointing to connect various 0 volt nodes to a single power 0 volts. This prevents high-currents flowing along sensitive feedback sensing circuits and disrupting the quality of the signal fed-back.

I should also say that the use of star-pointing does not restrict you from using individual copper planes that are star pointed together.

For the [L5973](https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/389/l5973d-1849286.pdf) device the GND pin is not a heavy current pin but rather a signal reference pin despite the data sheet giving no clue about it. The quality of GND determines in no small way the quality of the feedback signal, the quality of the internal reference and the quality of the error amplifier (via COMP). It is also a digital reference input for INHIBIT and SYNC. It takes very little current (circa 5 mA).

Comment: That's very helpful, as always.  Can I ask how you can see this: "It takes very little current (circa 5 mA)." ?

Comment: @jonathanjo DC characteristics on page 5.

Comment: Ah yes I definitely was confused by "quiescent" in  "Total operating quiescent current (5mA)".  I (now!) can see that the main current return to ground doesn't go through the chip at all.

Answer (score 2):

They're telling you to sense the output voltage away from the inner switching loop, which will have large ground currents that will cause voltage drops. If you measured there any voltage drop would be added to the output voltage. Instead you should measure voltage between the output rail and it's matching ground, which is the voltage the load would see.

If you look at your layout example they have the voltage measured on the opposite side of the circuit from the switching loop.